# ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Technologies portfolio must exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was trying to save nested attributes for technologies with portfolio, I have the following code:
portfolio.rb (model)

```
class Portfolio < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :technologies
  # do not accept the insertion if name is blank
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :technologies,
                                 reject_if: lambda{ |attrs| attrs['name'].blank? }
  validates_presence_of :title, :body, :main_image, :thumb_image
  include Placeholder
  validates_presence_of :title, :body, :main_image, :thumb_image

  # class method - custom scope
  def self.angulars
    where(subtitle: "Angular")
  end 

  # lambda - custom scope
  scope :ruby_on_rails_p_items, -> { where(subtitle: "Ruby on Rails") }

  # callbackss
  after_initialize :set_defaults

  def set_defaults
    self.main_image ||= Placeholder.image_generator(height:'600', width:'400')
    self.thumb_image ||= Placeholder.image_generator(height:'350', width:'200')
  end 
end
```

technology.rb model:

```
class Technology < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :portfolio
end
```

Now when I go to the rails console and try to insert multiple attributes:

```
Portfolio.create!(title: "Web App", subtitle: "asadasd", body: "sadsadas", technologies_attributes: [{name: "Ruby"}, {name: "Rails"}, {name: "Angula"}, {name: "Ionic"}])
```

It gave me this error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Technologies portfolio must exist
    from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/validations.rb:78:in `raise_validation_error'
```

Any idea what am I missing here?

Schema for both technology and portfolio:

```
  create_table "portfolios", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "subtitle"
    t.text     "body"
    t.text     "main_image"
    t.text     "thumb_image"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  end

  create_table "technologies", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "portfolio_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
    t.index ["portfolio_id"], name: "index_technologies_on_portfolio_id", using: :btree
  end
```

COMPLETE ERROR MESSAGE:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Technologies portfolio must exist
    from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/validations.rb:78:in `raise_validation_error'
    from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/validations.rb:50:in `save!'
    from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:30:in `save!'
    from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:324:in `block in save!'
    from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:395:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
    from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:232:in `block in transaction'
    from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:189:in `within_new_transaction'
    from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:232:in `transaction'
    from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:211:in `transaction'
    from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:392:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
    from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:324:in `save!'
    from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/suppressor.rb:45:in `save!'
    from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:51:in `create!'
    from (irb):3
    from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:65:in `start'
    from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/commands/console_helper.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `console'
    from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
    from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from /Users/mac/Desktop/DevCampPortfolio/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
    from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in load'
    from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
    from /Users/mac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/mac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
2.3.1 :004 > Portfolio.create!(title: "Web App", subtitle: "asadasd", body: "sadsadas", main_image: 'some value', thumb_image: 'some image')
```

Comment: Can you post validations of technology.rb? I think you have a validation on portfolio_id in technology, you might need to remove that this to work.

Comment: @PramodShinde: updated the description thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have validation on `Portfolio`

```
validates_presence_of :title, :body, :main_image, :thumb_image
```

And you are passing only `:title, :subtile, :body` but not `:main_image, :thumb_image`

```
Portfolio.create!(title: "Web App", subtitle: "asadasd", body: "sadsadas", technologies_attributes: [{name: "Ruby"}, {name: "Rails"}, {name: "Angula"}, {name: "Ionic"}])
```

Above code expecting saving of `Portfolio` should be successful, so it can use portfolio_id in `Technology`, but it isn't happening here you need to pass in all required parameter to `Portfolio.create!`

```
Portfolio.create!(title: "Web App", subtitle: "asadasd", body: "sadsadas", main_image: 'some value', thumb_image: 'some image',
  technologies_attributes: [{name: "Ruby"}, {name: "Rails"}, {name: "Angula"}, {name: "Ionic"}])
```

**Update:**

As you are using `Rails 5.x`, In Rails 5.x (onwards) all belongs_to association validates(belongs_to association) presence true by default, add `optional: true` to your Technology Model. [Read more about this](https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/02/15/rails-5-makes-belong-to-association-required-by-default.html)

```
class Technology < ApplicationRecord 
  belongs_to :portfolio, optional: true 
end
```

Comment: I've set up a default there (via   def set_defaults) in case the user will not upload the images, there is a default url for the images. the error says: RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Technologies portfolio must exist, I am not sure w/c technologies portfolio it means.

Comment: It means technologies needs portfolio/portfolio_id while saving. Can you try saving only portfolio without passing technologies_attributes? and Also see the portfolio.errors for more details

Comment: Yes it works without the technologies_attributes. It saved. what do you think is the issue?

Comment: And are you sure Technology model don't have any validations?

Comment: Error clearly says that Portfolio object is not getting saved see if you can check all the errors on the object with `portfolio.errors` after assigning it to variable like `portfolio = Portfolio.create!(....)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184607/discussion-between-pramod-shinde-and-james-hedegon).

Comment: Thank you. Works for me.

Answer (score 5):

Making the `belongs_to :portfolio` association optional is not solving the problem. All you are doing by passing in `optional: true` is skipping validation, which is not useful if you actually want to set up a database schema with Model associations.

The underlying cause of the problem is that Active Record is attempting to create a `Technology` object before the `Portfolio` object has been committed to the database. `accepts_nested_attributes_for` is special in that it creates an instance of the associated model (`Technology` in this case) through the parent model (`Portfolio`). To do this Active Record needs to know about the relation between the two models, and it must also have a foreign key to tie the associated `Technology` object to a specific `Portfolio`.

If you were to create a `Portfolio` object first, and then a `Technology` object separately you wouldn't have a problem:

```
portfolio = Portfolio.create!(title: "Web App", subtitle: "asadasd", body: "sadsadas")

Technology.create!(name: 'aoeifjeao', portfolio_id: portfolio.id)
=> #<Technology id: 10, name: "aoeifjeao", portfolio_id: 17, created_at: "2019-12-07 03:54:47", updated_at: "2019-12-07 03:54:47">
```

The reason this works is clear if you inspect the SQL queries generated by the `Technology.create` code:

```
(0.4ms)  BEGIN
Portfolio Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "portfolios".* FROM "portfolios" WHERE "portfolios"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 17], ["LIMIT", 1]]
SQL (1.6ms)  INSERT INTO "technologies" ("name", "portfolio_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "aoeifjeao"], ["portfolio_id", 17], ["created_at", "2019-12-07 03:54:47.668662"], ["updated_at", "2019-12-07 03:54:47.668662"]]
(41.0ms)  COMMIT
```

Note that the first thing that happens is Active Record looks for a `Portfolio` from the database with a specific `id`. It then inserts a new record into the `technologies` table with the same `portfolio_id`.

This is what happens when you create a model with an association using Active Record. It looks for the parent model in the database first using the `id` you specified, and then that becomes the foreign key of the child model.

Returning to your code, when you call `Portfolio.create`, what you are actually trying to do is create both the parent and child objects, plus set up their association, all before any records are saved to the database.

What is actually happening is that `Portfolio.create` gets broken up into two steps. First `Portfolio.new` is called, which instantiates (but doesn't save) the `Portfolio` Object:

```
portfolio = Portfolio.new(title: "Web App", subtitle: "asadasd", body: "sadsadas", technologies_attributes: [{name: "Ruby"}])
=> #<Portfolio id: nil, title: "Web App", subtitle: "asadasd", body: "sadsadas", main_image: "http://placehold.it/600x400", thumb_image: "http://placehold.it/350x200", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

Note that our nested attributes have already been used to instantiate a `Technology` Object through the `Portfolio` association, but the foreign key `portofolio_id` is `nil`:

```
portfolio.technologies
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Technology id: nil, name: "Ruby", portfolio_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>]>
```

Next, `Portfolio.save` is called, which throws `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid` validation error. This is telling you that the `Technology` object requires a `Portfolio` association, which it does not have because `portfolio_id` is still `nil`.

When setting up `belongs_to` and `has_many` relationships, Active Record attempts to automatically guess the inverse association based on heuristics, typically by looking at the table names. It's usually pretty good at it, but sometimes you need to be explicit and declare the `inverse_of` relationships between the two models.

```
# portfolio.rb

class Portfolio < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :technologies, inverse_of: :portfolio
end
```

```
# technology.rb

class Technology < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :portfolio, inverse_of: :technologies
end
```